# Automapper create map from custom method

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class Entity
{
      public string Name { get; set; }
}       
public class SomethingDto
{
     public string NameChanged { get; set; }
     public void Mapping(Entity something)
     {
         NameChanged = something.Name;
     }          
}
```

I want to use the Mapping Method of the DTO to create the map as the following way:

```
conf.CreateMap<Entity, SomethingDto>().ForMember(t => t.NameChanged, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.Name));
```

There is a way in AutoMapper to create the maps with custom methods, who works with his projection?

Comment: You can have a constructor instead. [The docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Construction).

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to do it like that, because that makes the DTO aware of the entity and that would throw out the separation you'd get.

Now in this case, the line `ForMember(t => t.NameChanged, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.Name))` will work because `Name` and `NameChanged` are both of type `string`. Say you'd like to do something along the lines of mapping identifier of type `string` with value '*20180120-00123456*' to two properties on the destination: a `DateTime` property and a `ProductId` property. You can do this two ways.

### Simple

You would write two mapping functions in the class where you make the mapping and do it along the lines of:

- `ForMember(t => t.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => RetrieveDate(t.Identifier)))`
- `ForMember(t => t.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => RetrieveProductId(t.Identifier)))`

### Complex

You would make a custom class `OrderIdentifier` (now I'm assuming the identifier is for an order) with only the `Id` property as `string`. Then you'd make two [custom type converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Custom-type-converters.md), like the article describes.