How to set different behavior in AutoMapper when creating a new entity, and doing a partial update?
I'm using Asp.Net with AutoMapper.
Say for example I have a User and a UserDto
    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserDto
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }

Sometimes I want to map a new User from a UserDto
    var user = = _mapper.Map<User>(userDto);

and when that happens I want to set the Mapper configuration profile such that a new Id is automatically created and CreatedAt is DateTime.Now
But sometimes I also want to use the dto for a partial update on an existing User.
    _mapper.Map(userDto, existingUser);

When that happens I don't want a new Id to be created, or the CreatedAt to be DateTime.Now for the existingUser (since it already has its own Id and CreatedAt time) and also I don't want any null fields from the dto to be mapped into existingUser (since existingUser may already have a value for it and the fact that the dto's field is null means that I don't need to update it in existingUser).
Now my question is : how do I configure my AutoMapper UserProfile so I can have both these behaviors. Or is it not possible?
I also tried to do a conditional check, if dest.Id is null, then dest.Id is Guid.NewGuid.ToString() but Id is a not nullable field, you can't do a null check on it. Same for CreatedAt.
So far the only work around I got is to create a factory method that will create a new user while filling in the Id and CreatedAt appropriately and then use automapper to map the dto's updated info into it. Automapper configuration will only map non-null values from the dto into the user. If i want a new user I'll use the factory method, if I want a partial update, I'll use the Automapper directly

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900590/automapper-create-map-from-custom-method showing how you can map specific members

@ste-fu oh thanks but I couldn't find my answer there
